# delete item from listfragment is not working properly

Tags: android, sqlite

Im doing a basic android app to learn about sqlite. The app just have a listfragment that list some products and the price like:

```
Pencil    1
Pen       1.20
...
```

And its possible to click in a item of the list to delete it. Im using cursorloader so the db operations are done in background. But Im getting a issue:

- When the user clicks in a item the item is not removed from the list, but if I close and open again the app all items of the list have been removed.

Do you know where is the issue? Why the fragmentlist is not updated by removing the clicked item after click in the item and why all items are being removed?

**// to list the products and the respective price**

```
public class ProductsFragment extends ListFragment implements OnClickListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
  private static final String[] PROJECTION=new String[] {
      Provider.Products._ID, Provider.Products.TITLE,
      Provider.Products.PRICE };

      private CursorAdapter cursorAdapter;


  public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(Provider.Products.CONTENT_URI, DBHelper.ALL_COLUMNS,
            null,null,null,null);
    String[] from = {DBHelper.TITLE, DBHelper.PRICE};
    int[] to = {R.id.title, R.id.price};

    cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.item, null, from, to, 0);

    setListAdapter(cursorAdapter);

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

  }
```

// **to delete a product**

```
@Override
  public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int pos, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, pos, id);

    getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(Provider.Products.CONTENT_URI,String.valueOf(id), null);

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item " + id + " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

**// cursorloader methods**

```
 @Override
  public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
    return new CursorLoader(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Provider.Products.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
  }


 @Override
  public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    cursorAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
  }


public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    cursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);
  }
```

**// Provider class delete method:**

```
@Override
  public int delete(Uri url, String where, String[] whereArgs) {
    return database.delete(DBHelper.TABLE_PRODUCTS, where, whereArgs);
  }
```

**same issue with:**

```
 @Override
  public int delete(Uri url, String where, String[] whereArgs) {
    int count=db.getWritableDatabase().delete(TABLE, where, whereArgs);

    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(url, null);

    return(count);
  }
```

**item.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/title"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      />
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/price"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Full ProductsFragment:

```
public class ConstantsFragment extends ListFragment implements OnClickListener, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

  private CursorAdapter cursorAdapter;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
  }

  public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(Provider.Constants.CONTENT_URI, DatabaseHelper.ALL_COLUMNS,
            null,null,null,null);
    String[] from = {DatabaseHelper.TITLE, DatabaseHelper.VALUE};
    int[] to = {R.id.title, R.id.value};

    cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row, null, from, to, 0);

    setListAdapter(cursorAdapter);

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

  }

  @Override
  public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.actions, menu);

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId()==R.id.add) {
      add();
      return(true);
    }

    return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
  }


  @Override
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
    AlertDialog dlg=(AlertDialog)dialog;
    EditText title=(EditText)dlg.findViewById(R.id.title);
    EditText value=(EditText)dlg.findViewById(R.id.value);

    values.put(DatabaseHelper.TITLE, title.getText().toString());
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.VALUE, value.getText().toString());

 getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(Provider.Constants.CONTENT_URI, values);

    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int pos, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, pos, id);

    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);
    getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(Provider.Constants.CONTENT_URI,String.valueOf(id), null);

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item id " + id + "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  private void add() {
    LayoutInflater inflater=getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View addView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_edit, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    builder.setTitle(R.string.add_title).setView(addView)
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, this)
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null).show();
  }

  @Override
  public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
    return new CursorLoader(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Provider.Constants.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
  }

  public void insertNote(String title, Double value){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.TITLE, title);
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.VALUE, value);

    Uri noteUri = getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(Provider.Constants.CONTENT_URI, values);
    Log.d("MainActivity", "Inserted" + noteUri.getLastPathSegment());
  }

  @Override
  public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    cursorAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
  }


  @Override
  public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    cursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

in on click after item deleted call to notifyDatasetChanged()

Comment: Thanks. I add cursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() but same issue.

Comment: @OzzyW try to restart loader before notifyDatasetChanged()

Comment: Thanks. But with that when a item is clicked all items disappear from the listfragment, so all items are removed.

Comment: With Toast.makeText(this, "Items deleted " + count , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT.show() its not working. Do you know why?

Comment: Log.d("MYINT", "value:", + count) dont show nothing in the logcat when item is clicked.

Comment: @OzzyW where u set onListItemClick()??

Comment: Thanks. The ProductsFragment extends ListFragment that has the onListItemClick().

Comment: @OzzyW but u need to set the listener domeghing like this:
    list.setOnListItemClick(LISTENET);
On ur case it should be this insread of LISTENER

Comment: In the code after "// to list the products and the respective price" I have setListAdapter(CursorAdapter) using a R.layout.item that I update the question witht it, it has a textview for the product title and other for the price.

Comment: im not uderstand u. but u need to set obclick listener on obhect of the list

Comment: Wrong answer ... when you are working with Loaders and ContentProvider and CursorLoaders there is no need for calling notifyDatasetChanged as swapCursor do this